# Как распознать строку с датой и преобразовать ее в Date (php)?

Tags: php

Парсим строку с датой выхода объявления на доске. 
Пример: "17:01, сегодня", или "23:51, вчера", или "17:01, 1 ноября".
Как перевести это значение в тип Date (php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).
Но есть нюанс - она работает только с текстовыми данными на английском языке, так что прежде чем скормить ей данные, стоит использовать для полученных данных или перевод или устанавливать для этого скрипта [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).